# Cannot find column 4

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

When I want to add a new row to the database receive an error message that I have this problem can anyone help me...
[image]

Comment: Try starting with index 0 rather than 1.

Comment: By the way, in the future, please post the code and the text of the error message in the body of your question.  Having all the pertinent details of your question only be in a screenshot is discouraged because it makes it impossible to find your question via text search.

Comment: Btw, you're using a DataGridView, but you're then trying to add a new record using TextBoxes as data source. Are you sure about this?

Comment: It's hard to read that image. We will be able to  help you better if you copy/paste the code into the question (using proper formatting) and then describe what and where the error happens.

Comment: As others have mentioned great input and suggestions, this is a debugging issue, it's sadly off topic here.

Comment: I'm sorry about screenshot i didnt know how to post code sorry ,,,,and yes i solve it with index 0 thank you all

Answer (score 3):

In VB.NET (and most other modern programming languages), array indicies start from 0. Try subtracting one from each index (0, 1, 2, 3 instead of 1, 2, 3, 4).